# SUM items & Quantity with Multiple Tables & IF MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to show all **Items with Quantity**. But the **Quantity is in different table**.

Example Output:

```
Item    Quantity
Item1   34
Item2   10
Item3   0
........
```

I have a code that can **count Quantity** but in **Single Item only.**

```
SELECT SUM(ROUND(Quantity)) FROM(
SELECT
COALESCE(SUM(od.Quantity),0) as 'Quantity'
FROM sts as T1
LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od ON T1.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
WHERE od.ItemId = '4786' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
COALESCE(SUM(od.Quantity),0) as 'Quantity'
FROM drs as T2
LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od ON T2.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
WHERE od.ItemId = '4786' 
UNION ALL  
SELECT 
COALESCE(SUM(IF(r.AddsToStock = '1', od.Quantity, 0 - od.Quantity)),0) as 'Quantity'
FROM stockadjustment as T3
LEFT JOIN reason as r ON r.ReasonId = T3.ReasonId
LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od ON T3.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId 
WHERE od.ItemId = '4786'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
COALESCE(SUM(IF(T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId, 0 - od.Quantity, -1 * od.Quantity)),0) as 'Quantity'
FROM issueslip as T4
LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od ON T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId 
WHERE od.ItemId = '4786'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
COALESCE(SUM(IF(T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId, 0 - od.Quantity, -1 * od.Quantity)),0) as 'Quantity'
FROM invoice as T4
LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od ON T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
WHERE od.ItemId = '4786') as t
```

**HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT THE ITEMS USING THIS CODE?**

**Table Name** `items` and the id is `ItemId`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x WHERE x` is the same as `INNER JOIN x`

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry I'm new to MySQL though its been years that I'm using it. Its my first time encountering too many joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create this stored function:

   ```
   DELIMITER //

   CREATE FUNCTION getItemQty(
       _itemID INT(10)
   )
   RETURNS INT
   BEGIN

   RETURN (SELECT 
           SUM(ROUND(Quantity)) 
       FROM (
           SELECT
               COALESCE(SUM(od.Quantity),0) as Quantity
           FROM sts as T1
           LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
               ON T1.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
           WHERE od.ItemId = _itemID
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 
               COALESCE(SUM(od.Quantity),0) as Quantity
           FROM drs as T2
           LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
               ON T2.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
           WHERE od.ItemId = _itemID
           UNION ALL  
           SELECT 
               COALESCE(
                   SUM(
                       IF(r.AddsToStock = '1', od.Quantity, 0 - od.Quantity)
                   ),0
               ) as Quantity
           FROM stockadjustment as T3
           LEFT JOIN reason as r 
               ON r.ReasonId = T3.ReasonId
           LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
               ON T3.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId 
           WHERE od.ItemId = _itemID
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 
               COALESCE(
                   SUM(
                       IF(T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId, 0 - od.Quantity, -1 * od.Quantity)
                   ),0
               ) as Quantity
           FROM issueslip as T4
           LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
               ON T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId 
           WHERE od.ItemId = _itemID
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 
               COALESCE(
                   SUM(
                       IF(T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId, 0 - od.Quantity, -1 * od.Quantity)
                   ),0
               ) as Quantity
           FROM invoice as T4
           LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
               ON T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
           WHERE od.ItemId = _itemID
       ) as t);
   END//
   ```
2. Use that query to fetch data.

   ```
   SELECT 
       ItemId,
       getItemQty(ItemId) AS quantity
   FROM items
   ```

Comment: Ill try it later cuz i need some sleep but i think this is what I'm looking for :) ill test it later. Thank you for answering (y)

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'i.ItemId' in 'where clause' `

Comment: I see, this is because we have two level of sub-queries that we cannot access the data of the outer query. Try the second query. If it don't work, I still got to things we could try.

Comment: I don't know how I can implement the `items` table with that queries. I'm out of idea. I really need your help.

Comment: You mean that the `items` table do not exists yet? Sorry I though, so let recapitulate, your items are spread all over the tables used in the query right and you want to regroup the data into a single table. Is that what you want?

Comment: Items table exist I just don't know how should I impement it with the code above.

Comment: To populate the items table or the items table is merely holding the ids that we must use in query in order to build the quantity/product view? The solution I've been working with you since yesterday is the second, but it is not too late to adjust that.

Comment: Yes cuz all products are in items table and the quantity I want to sum is in orderset_details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118455/discussion-between-jonathan-parent-levesque-and-meyka-jograt).

Comment: How about the stored function approach (see the update)

Comment: The coode you suggested looks compromising to me all mark this as an answer and review your suggest.

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND SIR!!!! THANK YOU!! NOW MY WORRIES FOR THE DEADLINE GOT LESSENED!

Comment: @Meyka Jograt Thank you, but I don't deserve so much credit, just take some note for the next time. Good success on your next assignment.